# Как вернуть новый массив из метода?

Tags: массивы, delphi, pascal, freepascal

Задача: написать функцию или процедуру, для  того чтобы удалить элемент из массива, по индексу `n` при этом массив нужно изменить, чтобы он был без пустого элемента. Как вернуть новый массив?

```
`procedure DeleteIndexElm(var arr:arrInteger;DelIndex:integer);
var newArrInt:arrInteger;i,j:integer;
begin
    if length(arr) < 1  then
        exit;
    j:=1;
    SetLength(newArrInt,length(arr)-1);
    for i := 1 to length(arr) do
    begin
        if i <> DelIndex then
        begin
            newArrInt[j] := arr[i];
            j:=j+1;
        end;
    end;
    SetLength(arr,Length(newArrInt));
    arr:=newArrInt;
end;`
```

Comment: Если что, то такая функция уже есть, называется [Delete()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Delete).

Comment: Я знаю, но, пытался сам реализовать эту функцию)

Comment: Не нужно так менять вопрос, задайте новый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type
  TArrayOfInteger: array of integer;

procedure DeleteArrayElement(var arr: TArrayOfInteger, index: integer);
begin
  ...
  SetLength(arr, Length(arr) - 1);
  ...
end;
```

---

> процедура работает как-то некорректно.

Индексация динамических массивов начинается с нуля.

```
j := 0;
SetLength(newArrInt, Length(arr) - 1);
for i := 0 to Length(arr) - 1 do
begin
  ...
end;
//SetLength(arr,Length(newArrInt));
```

Comment: Добрый день, помогите пожалуйста, процедура работает как-то некорректно. Если элементов в массиве становится меньше половины, выбрасывает ошибку. Gdb фиксирует ошибку при присвоении нового массива к старому. Код процедуры сверху, спасибо!

Comment: @Taurinz Пожалуйста. Успехов!